# Should we allow questions like "How popular is AnimeX in CountryX?"

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Should we allow questions like "How popular is AnimeX in CountryX?" if ever a certain user is curious about the popularity of a certain anime in a certain place or country?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My current opinion on this is leaning towards no.

Here's why:

1. Such a title begs for "non constructive" closure. Unless there are published and official numbers, it's going to be difficult to get an answer. The last thing we want is differing opinions from everyone over how popular they *think* X is in Y country.
2. The second problem is that popularity can change. Thus rendering the answers obsolete. A show can come out in Japan first. And is popular only in Japan and fansub watchers. Then later when it gets dubbed in English, it becomes in popular in North America and Europe.

In other words, I see a high potential for such questions to degrade.

That said, I'm not strongly against this type of question. I'm willing to be swayed in favor of allowing them if anyone provides some good counter-arguments.

Comment: Just want to follow up since it's about anime's popularity, how about questions that asks for awards that a certain anime received in Japan or worldwide?

Comment: That would become a [list question](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/348/what-is-the-status-of-list-questions-on-this-site). Which, if the list isn't too long or too often updated, would most likely be fine. The key difference here is that a list of awards is *objective* - at least more so than how "popular" a show is.

Comment: I'll note that there might be an issue with finding the suitable sources that show what awards X anime received. But that's a different issue.